# Different prefix for each Cog?

Tags: python, discord.py

Is it possible to set a prefix for each cog?

For example the Cog with admin commands has the prefix `pa!` and the cog for some fun commands `pf!`.

Without using `on_message`.

Edit:
I guess I have to go more in detail:

- My cog for serverstats has a command called 'stats', this command should get
  triggered when I'm using `pa!`
- My cog for fun has a 'stats' command too. This should be triggered when I'm
  using `pf!`

My only thought up to now was to set the default prefix to `p!` and then call the command `astats`. But I want to have a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the prefix used in a command using `ctx.prefix`. So you could run a check like this:

```
@commands.command()
async def sample_command(self, ctx):
    if ctx.prefix != "pa!":
        return
```

And previously enabling those prefixes `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("pa!", "pf!"))`

Comment: Well I guess this should be a nice solution. I'll try this.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Maxsc's answer, you can define a [`cog_check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_check) method that will be called before every command from the cog:

```
class FunCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.prefix = "pf!"
    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        return ctx.prefix == self.prefix
```

In your main code, you can use a callable that consumes the prefixes from the cogs to determine which prefixes to pay attention to.  This would get passed as your [`command_prefix`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix)

```
def get_prefixes(bot, message):
    cog_prefixes = (cog.prefix for cog in bot.cogs.values() if hasattr(cog, 'prefix'))
    default_prefixes = ("!")
    return (*cog_prefixes, *default_prefixes)
```

Comment: How would that look in the main file? How exactly do we use this method to "pass" it in the `command_prefix`?

Comment: @CaptAngryEyes as a keyword argument to `commands.Bot`: `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefixes)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an interesting question as I have had the same one for some time. I had an idea for implementing this myself although it does use the `on_message` function but not just that.

Basically my thought was to override the cog class and add a way for it to denote what prefix it should have. I thought use a custom argument in `@commands.command` to signify what prefix to use but this was for commands themselves.

Then in the `on_message` function you will need to determine there what command to call. Possibly the use of a global dict that correlates what prefix to what command.

This was just my own personal brainstorming and you will need to keep in mind if you allow each server to set their own prefixes and how to go about allowing that plus allowing them to set custom prefixes for each command. Good luck I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but different commands for every server for example was not my plan. I only want to split some commands to other prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your commands are in the `on_message` event, you can split the message content with spaces (`" "`) and check the first element of the splitted list for the prefix and put the avaibale commands under an if statement. This could work, but will be slighly resource heavy depending on the amount of the commands