# How do you set a different prefix for each cog?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am a little way through devolving my discord bot and I had started making cogs for my different commands. But I wanted to know if there was any way to set a separate prefix for each cog without setting it for each command.

Cog so far: ⬇️

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 


class Greetings(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    
    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
        await ctx.send(f"Hello {member.name}")
        
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Greetings(bot))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different prefix for each Cog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105582/different-prefix-for-each-cog)

Comment: Yes, But is there any way to do it without adding a if statement after each command?

Comment: It's a duplicate either way. That should be added as an extra answer to the original question.